# classification of user population by access rights

Tags: python, algorithm, classification

What I am trying to do is to classify the employees by the roles they have
in an organization.  This is computed by grabbing all the permissions, or
access lists, they have for the target enterprise software.

There are potentially 10000s of users and dozens of permissions per user.

Edit:  when there are large amounts of users, the vast majority will have a limited set permissions.  For example, they might all have `Employee` only.  More complicated cases are power users and there will be way less.

Also, don't be misled by the permission names I have given, like Acct1/Acct2, they're just meant to give a feel for the the domain.  The solution I am looking for should conceptually work even with randomnly-assigned primary key integers like to you see in many ORM stores - there is **no** implied relationship between permissions.

```
import pprint
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)

def classify(employees):
    """employees assigned the same set 
    of permissions are grouped together"""
    roles = dict()
    for user, permissions in employees.items():
        permissions = list(permissions)
        permissions.sort()
        key = tuple(permissions)
        members = roles.setdefault(key, set([]))
        members.add(user)
    return roles

everyone = {
    "Jim": set(["Employee","Acct1","Manager"]),
    "Marion": set(["Employee","Acct1","Acct2"]),
    "Omar": set(["Employee","Acct1"]),
    "Kim": set(["Employee","Acct1"]),
    "Tyler": set(["Employee","Acct1"]),
    "Susan": set(["Employee","Marketing","Manager"]),
}

result = classify(everyone)
print("pass1")
pp.pprint(result)
```

At this point, the classification system returns the following:

`{   ('Acct1', 'Acct2', 'Employee'): set(['Marion']),
    ('Acct1', 'Employee'): set(['Kim', 'Omar', 'Tyler']),
    ('Acct1', 'Employee', 'Manager'): set(['Jim']),
    ('Employee', 'Manager', 'Marketing'): set(['Susan'])}`

From this, we can eyeball the data and manually assign some meaningful names to those roles.

```
Senior Accountants - Marion
Accounting Managers - Jim
Accountants - Kim, Omar, Tyler
Marketing Manager - Susan
```

The assignment is manual, but the intent is that it remains as "sticky" as possible even when people get hired or leave and when permission change.

Let's do a second pass.

Someone's decided to rename `Acct2` to `SrAcct`.  People get hired, Kim leaves.

This is represented by the following employee permissions:

`everyone2 = {
        "Jim": set(["Employee","Acct1","Manager"]),
        "Marion": set(["Employee","Acct1","SrAcct"]),
        "Omar": set(["Employee","Acct1"]),
        "Tyler": set(["Employee","Acct1"]),
        "Milton": set(["Employee","JuniorAcct"]),
        "Susan": set(["Employee","Marketing","Manager"]),
        "Tim": set(["Employee","Marketing"]),
    }`

The output this time is:

`{   ('Acct1', 'Employee'): set(['Omar', 'Tyler']),
    ('Acct1', 'Employee', 'Manager'): set(['Jim']),
    ('Acct1', 'Employee', 'SrAcct'): set(['Marion']),
    ('Employee', 'JuniorAcct'): set(['Milton']),
    ('Employee', 'Manager', 'Marketing'): set(['Susan']),
    ('Employee', 'Marketing'): set(['Tim'])}`

Ideally, we'd recognize that

```
Senior Accountants - Marion
Accounting Managers - Jim
Accountants - Omar, Tyler
Marketing Manager - Susan
new role - Tim
new role - Milton
```

Tim's roles will now be named a `Marketer`, while Milton a `Junior Accountant`.

What's important is that the role name assignment is stable enough to allow reasoning about an employee population even as people get hired and leave (most frequent) and as permissions are added or renamed (much less frequent).  It's OK to ask the end user from time to time to assign new role names or to decide between ties.  But most of the time, it should run along smoothly.  What it **shouldn't** do it guess wrong and erroneously label a set of users as the wrong role name.

The problem I have is that it is easy to eyeball, but both the set of permissions and the set of users that define a role can change.  Classification time is important, but the value of this classification mechanism goes up as the number of users and permissions increase.

I've tried extracting "the subset of permissions that define a role".  For example, `Employee` is assigned to everyone so can be ignored. While `(Manager, Acct1)`, `(Manager, Marketing)` uniquely belong to Jim and Susan.  Trouble is that runs into a combinational explosion once you get the easy 20-30% of the cases out and it never finishes.

What I thinking now is to back and compute the new employee-permission role classification for each generation and then backtrack to get a fuzzy matching "best fit" compared to the previous generation. Pick the ones that are reasonably unambiguous and ask the user to decide on ties and to assign new role names as needed.

For example, an exact match on permissions and a reasonable match on employees means that `'Omar', 'Tyler'` are still `Accountants` at pass 2.  On the other hand, if Marion had left and I had `"Jane": set(["Employee","Acct1","SrAcct"])`, I'd have to ask the end user to arbitrate and identify her as a `Senior Accountant`.

I've worked with **Jaccard Similarity** (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index) in the past, but I am unsure how it applies to cases where both sides can change (`Acct2` => `SrAcct` as well as employee changes).

I am pretty sure this kind of logic has been needed before, so I'm hoping for recommendations for algorithms to look at and strategies to follow.

Oh, and I am looking for reasonably stand-alone approaches that I can implement, and reason about, within the context of a larger Python app.  Not for *machine-learning* recommendations about how to configure the likes of **TensorFlow** to do this for me.  Though, if push came to shove, I could call a batch to do the matching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing:

1. before calculating the classification for new set of user/access, save the old ones, along with their assigned names.
2. after the new classifications are calculated, find the closest match between the new and the old and transfer the names if the confidence is high enough.

   - full user match?  then it's a match.  I transform the user set into a sorted tuple of users to match via dictionary.
   - full permissions match?  Again, it's a match.  Again, check via a set to sorted tuple tranform lookup against a dictionary.
   - For each current left unmatched, I calculate a Jaccard similarity for each unmatched previous, separately on its users and its permissions.  So, that could go O(N2)on the numbers of unmatched.  Append each match to that classification's list.  Sort the list in order of score (from the `calc` function below) and, last step, only pick one automatically if there is large enough difference with the next closest match.

`

```
    class Match(object):

        #these are weighing coefficients - I consider roles/permissions more important because of the expected user churn.
        con_roles = .7
        con_users = .3
        con_other = .07

        threshold = .7

        def calc(self):
            #could have anything you want here, really.
            self.similarity = self.con_roles * self.simroles + self.con_users * self.simusers
```

OK, I am leaving a lot out, but basically, you can apply a simple Jaccard similarity algo to both the user and role side and put those numbers into a suitable equation to see what's a close match.  If not satified, ask the user to assign the names again, as a last resort.

Hopefully that'll help someone if they end up looking for something similar.

Answer (score 1):

This will be a so-so answer, so apologies, but your problem is very wide and requires some logic rather than some specific code.

Perhaps this problem will be better addressed as "tags"? I mean a person could be both an employee, a guy in marketing, and a manager, all at the same time (and I presume will have permissions of all 3).

So I suggest a different approach - instead of grouping accounts by their respective permissions, and only then naming them manually, first classify and name the permissions (at least the more popular and stable among them) and then assign each employee to the correct category (or several) by giving each employee tags that encapsulate multiple permissions each.

Then, you will have quite a few users or permissions unclassified, but hopefully then you can ask users to do a bit of classification for you (for example, describe their position/permissions) and work with your approach on a much smaller problem set.

That way you can be sure that when a new employee enters, he is given the proper tag by looking at his permissions and deciding where he fits in. And when an employee leaves, it makes no difference, because he doesn't individually effects the permissions and tags.

Comment: Tagging implies that multiple tags can be applied to an object.  Those are, in a sense, the permissions.  Which are arbitrary and can't really be "pre-classified".  However, when you put all the permissions granted to a particular user, that gives them a unique profile that you can reason about them as a group.  For example, you might just have people with `Employee, Manager` permissions.  In which case, you would reason in terms of `Managers`, not `Managers Accounting`, `Manager Marketing` because they would then `look the same` to the system.

Comment: and the whole point is to simplify reasoning about huge employee populations.  Any system that requires manual preparation and reasoning, at the individual employee level, is a no-go.

Comment: I dont think that "tags" and permissions are equal, a tag of "Manager" can be applied to a group of 3 separate permissions that all must come together for the tag to apply

Comment: I apologize if that is insufficient for your use case, i'll remove my answer?

Comment: No, not at all.  It's a reasonable answer to a rather broad question.  And if you remove it, others will have the same idea.

Answer (score 1):

What you're really creating here is a single tree of organizational hierarchy.  Your grouping algorithm is already capable of that.  You're not showing them within a single hierarchy, but they could easily be displayed that way.

The "subjective" part of your organization is deciding when it is appropriate to combine branches into a single organizational role, and deciding in which order to sort the permissions when creating the branches (i.e. do you want to have a single manager branch, with divisions below that, or do you want to have department branches, each containing a manager branch).

Unfortunately, there's no way for a machine to know those preferences.  You're going to have to make all those decisions, especially if you're going to require a 0% false positive rate.

The easiest way I can think of to provide this preference information to the algorithm would be to give it an ordered list of permission "weights' it will use when building the hierarchy.  For a first pass, you could just order them by how many people have that permission.  It's possible that you might need more complex "weighting" than a single set of ordered permissions.  For a more complex weighting, you would need to specify more complex "rules" that check membership (or non-membership) in multiple permission sets.

The second bit of information would likely be provided interactively.  Given a display of the entire organizational chart, you would choose which permission sets should be combined into a single organizational set.  This is where you would also assign display names for your roles to each permission set group(s).

As far as being able to respond to hires/fires, it shouldn't be a problem so long as the permissions are the same.  As far as adding and removing permissions from users, you would have to store previous permissions and groupings and match them against current permissions for each user to prompt someone to either okay the change to the role permission set, or to form a new branch with the new permission.

Comment: interesting.  but please note that each employee is only tied to one `role`.  There is no relationship, **here**, between `Accountant` and `Senior Accountant` because they don't have the same access rights.  So they are in different roles/buckets.  I can do a Jaccard-based matching between roles for similarity.  Or compare them outright.  That's done and works. The point here is only to keep those user-assigned bucket/role names **stable** as the organization changes.  It's only a naming concern, not a hierarchical one.

Comment: Yes, a user would only be part of 1 role group.  I think a good way of thinking about the stability of a role is deciding which differences to ignore.  This is where thinking about the organization as a hierarchy can be useful, because it allows you to set up rules about when to collapse and merge branches.  For example, you could create a rule where by any changes that would create a branch superset below ([Acct1, Employee]) would just automatically collapse into that Role.

Comment: See, I am trying to bypass the very notion of rules and just match on the user-role groupings **mathematically**.  In a company with 500 employees the admin will look at a role with 380 users, and say "yup that's our Regular Employee" role.  They'll look at Jim and say "he's an Accounting Manager".  Well-run companies already do this: new mgr for an accounting dept?  Clone the user profile of a reference existing Accounting Mgr.  If I can re-match the role names reliably, no need to know the ins and outs of permissions like "PYRARG" vs "PYRBRZ" (**which customers typically rename anyway**).